# AssertionError: expected '2023-02-21T20:31:37.690Z' to include '2023-02-21T20:31:37.69Z' mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am getting assertion error where request Date='2023-02-21T20:31:37.690Z' and response date='2023-02-21T20:31:37.69Z'

the assertion is like this

```
expect(request.startDate)contains(response.body.startDate);
```

Is there any other way to compare date strings using mocha assertions in js

Comment: Is the string itself important? Because the string content here is different but both strings are representations of *exactly* the same point in time. So, if string is important - the test has found a problem correctly. If the exact string representation *isn't* important, then do you just need to check the datetime both point to?

Comment: As VLAZ said, if the missing trailing zero doesn't matters, just convert both strings into a Date object and compare the timestamps.

Comment: The exact string representation is not important but the assertion is failing coz the request time has extra characters